# What the Error in my Regex to to check a string contains a-z or A-Z

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

here is my code o check whether a string contain any other character than a-z OR A-Z.

```
        Regex  pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        if (pattern.IsMatch(txtCustName.Text))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Name contains some Invalid Characters");

            txtCustName.Focus();
        }
```

It still showing error msg even I'm typing he correct string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression is ok. Negate predicate:

```
if (! pattern.IsMatch(txtCustName.Text))
```